# How to dynamically add elements in an array inside a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several sheets and I need to create an array with only the wanted sheets.
So I have this code that skips some hardcoded sheet names, but I don't know how to add the wanted sheets in my array 'sheets_names_array'.
I have this code:

```
    ' make an array with the sheet names we want to parse
Dim sheets_names_array() As Variant, sheet As Variant

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Qlik Ingestion"
            'Do nothing
        Case "Dropdown Values"
            'Do nothing
        Case "VBmacro"
            'Do nothing
        Case Else
             'MsgBox ws.Name
             sheets_names_array.Add (ws.Name)
    End Select
Next
```

But the 'Add' method doesnt work. Do you know how to solve this please?
I have seen documentation that uses ReDim but I am not sure how to loop through the elements of the 'sheets_names_array' table

Comment: does it need to be an array? Would a collection do instead?

Comment: yes, it could be a collection. is it looped the same way? can I do `For Each sheet In sheets_names_array` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a collection instead

```
Dim sheets_names_col As New Collection
```

and add your items like

```
sheets_names_col.Add ws.Name
```

---

```
Dim sheets_names_col() As New Collection

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Qlik Ingestion", "Dropdown Values", "VBmacro"
            ' do nothing
        Case Else
            sheets_names_col.Add ws.Name
    End Select
Next ws
```

And you can loop it like

```
Dim sheet As Variant
For Each sheet In sheets_names_col
    Debug.Print sheet
Next sheet
```